Autocompleted code uses the wrong code style settings in Visual Studio 2022
I use TABS as the whitespace character, CRLF as the line break thing, and I position my curly braces like this:
private bool Example() {
    return true;
}

So, not like this:
private bool Example()
{
    return false;
}

I have my VS 2022 C# text editor settings set to be the same way. Still, somehow whenever I use autocompleted code, for example ctor + [tab], or when Visual Studio adjusts namespaces in a file, it always uses the exact opposite of what my setting are. It is really annoying and I don't want to have to fix it manually every time...
I've scoured the settings in Visual Studio, but I didn't find anything else that could affect these things. How could I change the autoformatting to use the same settings as the C# text editor? Thanks.

Have you tried Ctrl+E, D or menu Edit / Adavanced / Format Document (where you can see the actual shortcut key).

Oh, thanks. I'll try it out. But isn't there some way to make the autocomplete format it correctly, without having to correct it manually afterwards? @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Btw., you can also use File Scoped Namespaces having no braces.

Is it possible there is an editorConfig file local to the project/solution overriding your IDE settings?

It seems to be a Visual Studio thing, since it happens in all projects. @AlexD

Why did you edit the position of the opening curly brace in the first example? You edited it so that it didn't make any sense. Please read the question before editing things. @marc_s

The following may be of interest: Code-style rule options, C# formatting options, and C# formatting options

Ensure that you have set the settings the way that you desire in VS. Then in VS, click Tools => Options... => expand Text Editor => expand C# => expand Code Style => click General => click Generate .editorconfig file from settings => click Save => click OK. Anytime you make any changes to the settings, repeat this process and choose to overwrite the existing file.

That seems to have worked, @user246821! So, I just need to save the .editorconfig file to the project? It's not possible to save it somewhere, so that it would work universally across projects?

You may try creating a .editorConfig file as described in Code-style rule options and Code style preferences.
In Visual Studio, change your settings as desired.
For example, if one would like to have the following code style:
public class Class1 
{
    public Class1() {
        
    }
}

Set desired settings:
In the Visual Studio menu:

Click Tools
Select Options...
Expand Text Editor
Expand C#
Expand Code Style
Expand Formatting
Select New Lines
Uncheck Place open brace on new line for methods and local functions
Click OK (This will close the Tools menu, but it's necessary in order for the settings to be saved properly before generating the .editorconfig file)

Generate .editorconfig:
In the Visual Studio menu:

Click Tools
Select Options...
Expand Text Editor
Expand C#
Expand Code Style
Select General
Click 
Select desired location (ie: folder) to save to.
Click Save. If the .editorconfig file already exists, one will see a prompt, that states: .editorconfig already exists. Do you want to replace it? Click Yes.
Click OK

Note: If one would like the .editorconfig file to apply to all of one's projects, ensure that you save it to the parent directory that contains all of your projects. For example, if one stores all project/solutions in %UserProfile%\Documents\Projects, then save the .editorconfig in %UserProfile%\Documents\Projects.

For more information see EditorConfig File hierarchy and precedence
According to Define consistent coding styles with EditorConfig:

After you edit your EditorConfig file, you must reload your code files
for the new settings to take effect.

Alternatively, one may follow the steps described in Define consistent coding styles with EditorConfig to create the .editorconfig file.

Test the changes:

Create a new Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) in Visual Studio (name: WindowsFormsApp1)

Add a class to the project (name: Class1.cs)

In Class1.cs, position the curor inside the curly braces for Class1, then type ctor. Next press the Tab key.



Resources:

Code-style rule options
Code style preferences
Define consistent coding styles with EditorConfig
C# formatting options
Where to put editorconfig?


I have made some additions based on the information provided by user246821. Here is a tested approach which can come into force.

Click "Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Code Style → General → New Lines → Generate .editorconfig file from settings" to export .editorconfig file, take care to ensure the file named as ".editorconfig" and keep it in the same directory as the .sln file.
Open the ".editorconfig" file which is just generated, find the statement "csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = all"(value is just for example) and modify it to "csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none"
You can perform the clean and rebuild operation of the solution or reboot the Visual Studio to ensure the changes take effect.


Why would you post an answer with information that I provided? That's plagiarism. If the information works for the OP, I'll post it as an answer myself.

I added that this content is based on the information you provided @user246821
